# How do I write a Gulp task that simply calls a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm striving to create a Gulp task that does nothing except calling a custom function. No, I have, no source files, and no, I have no destination files. I just want to call a custom function in a standalone task, so I can have other tasks depending on it.

For the love of me, I've checked Google and SO and I couldn't find an example. The closest I've come with is this

```
var through = require('through2');

gulp.task(
    'my-custom-task',
    function ()
    {
        return through.obj(
            function write(chunk, enc, callback) {
                // here is where the custom function is called
                myCustomFunction('foo', 'bar');
                callback(null, chunk);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Now this does call `myCustomFunction`, but when I run the task with `gulp my-custom-task`, I can see the task starting but not finishing.

> ```
> [10:55:37] Starting 'clean:tmp'...
> [10:55:37] Finished 'clean:tmp' after 46 ms
> [10:55:37] Starting 'my-custom-task'...
> ```

How should I write my task correctly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just want a task that runs some function, then just do that:

```
gulp.task('my-custom-task', function () {
    myCustomFunction('foo', 'bar');
});
```

If your function does something asynchronously, it should call a callback at the end, so gulp is able to know when it’s done:

```
gulp.task('my-custom-task', function (callback) {
    myCustomFunction('foo', 'bar', callback);
});
```

---

As for why your solution does not work, using `through` is a way to work with streams. You can use it to create handlers which you can `.pipe()` into gulp streams. Since you have nothing actually using gulp streams, there is no need for you to create a stream handler and/or use through here.

Comment: Now this is easy after you've figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: @J.Doe, how do you import function that is in another file into your gulp task?

Comment: @bartosz.baczek You can import a function for gulp just like any other thing you can import using `require`.

Comment: @Poke Echhh, the dark sides of using typescript - now I don' t even know how to import simple function in js. So ok, I guess I need to use 'const boo = require('path/to/file/with/function.js') in my task file. But what do i do in file with function? I have function testFunction() { return 'testPassed'; }, but when i call it in task i get "testFunction is not a function" error.

Comment: Well, if you’re using TypeScript, it depends on what kind of module system you use for it. If you’re using ES imports, you can just export a function using `export function foobar () { … }` in one module and then import that using `import { foobar } from './my-module';` elsewhere. `require` on its own returns a module, so in your case you would have to do `boo.testFunction()` but that assumes that you correctly export the function through `module.exports`.